# sysfs interface for Android HAL and Linux Device Drivers

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, linux-kernel, hal

Why is SYSFS interface is perffered for communication between Android HAL and Device Drivers? Are they any other interfaces which can be used for communication between user space and kernel space in *Android*?

Comment: From my conversations with other engineers I got to know Sysfs might not be only interface for user and kernel communications, app developers can still use IOCTLS and other interfaces to communicate to kernel space.

Answer (score 0):

Other communication interface between user space and kernel space:
system call, ioctl, proc filesystem, netlink socket.

As i know, sysfs is developed to solve the proc file system contains include so many not process relative behavior. sysfs has the feature of ATTRIBUTE which can access kernel easily.